# Strong validator than valid_referers for nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to connect and isolate all direct links that are going to my backend

I have a website and backend, which is also on Nginx.

I want to use something that cannot be bypassed with settings, so what do you prefer?

I was using valid_referers and add my domains there, but that can be easily bypassed